# Database structure in Mongo DB

Tags: json, mongodb, datatables

I have one third party web services which provides data in
JSON, the structure is below:

[image]
That web services provides a total no of 22,000 records.

I am creating a scheduler that scrapes those records and saves them in a MongoDB collection.

I require some keys from Parent JSON like "query", "countyrName" etc parameter and some from "results" with inner JSON.

I want to display the data in an html table and want to add sorting and pagination with the jquery plugin Datatables.

How can I structure the data, so that I do not have any negative performance impacts? How can I further improve the performance?

Comment: Please do not use images to show the output of a program.

Comment: This is very hard to answer. A general rule for nosql is that you take into account how you want to access the data and structure your documents accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, you are right but please suggest me what is the best way which cannot impact Mongo DB performance and I only need to show those data on my UI using Datatable with pagination.

Comment: By Datatable, you mean the jquery plugin?

Comment: yes Datatable using Jquery for UI with pagination and ajax call to our Rest API.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display all the data in a flat table, you should structure your documents accordingly. This does not impact the performance.

If you want to display all data with jquery Datatables with sorting and pagination, you would have to send all 22,000 documents to the client. I suspect that this would make the whole application very slow in two ways:

- It would increase the load time of the page as a lot of data has to be loaded at once
- The sorting would be very slow, as the browser has to sort all 22,000 entries in javascript.

So you should do the sorting and pagination in the database (that is what it is for) and only fetch the requested data. To speed up the sorting in the db, you should create indexes on the fields you want to sort by.

If you want to keep the Datatables plugin, you should at least order the data the way you want to display it initially and add an index on that field.